# Python pandas fuzzy logic

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-logic

I currently have a dataset that needs to be fuzzy logic joined. Dataframe df1 is the smaller reference table with around 10 observations. Dataframe df2 is my main dataframe with around 2000 observations where the fuzzy logic join needs to be performed. I present the example and my attempt below.

```
import difflib
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,2,3,4,5],'not_shifted':['one','two','three','four','five']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'values':[['test'],['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f'],['f'],['f']],'not_shifted':[np.nan,'one','too','three','fours','five','six',np.nan,'one']})

# my approach
df2['not_shifted'] = df2['not_shifted'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['not_shifted'])[0])
```

I get the following error:
List out of range

> TypeError: 'float' object is not utterable

If I replace the np.nan with something else, I get another error:

> List out of range

Answer (score 1):

You get `TypeError` because dataframe df2 has nan values, you have to drop it.

Another problem: df1 does not have a rule for 'six' and `df2['not_shifted'] = df2['not_shifted'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['not_shifted'])[0])` generates a error `List out of range` because one of the lists is empty.

You code will look like (or you may use your_approach if you add to df1 a rule for 'six').

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import difflib

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'number':[1,2,3,4,5],'not_shifted':['one','two','three','four','five']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'values':[['test'],['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f'],['f'],['f']],'not_shifted':[np.nan,'one','too','three','fours','five','six',np.nan,'one']})

# Drop nan value
df2=df2.dropna()

# You cat write [0] because df1 does not have 'six'
df2['not_shifted'] = df2['not_shifted'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['not_shifted']))
print df2
```

Output:

```
  not_shifted values
1       [one]    [a]
2       [two]    [b]
3     [three]    [c]
4      [four]    [d]
5      [five]    [e]
6          []    [f]
8       [one]    [f]
```

Comment: Hello Serenity, Thank you for the quick response and solution :)

Comment: Hello Serenity, How do i get rid of the square brackets in the dataframe. The answer is correct, however, the square brackets in the solution is causing a bit of confusion. What is the purpose of defining a list in this dataframe? Thanks.